# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpwl

Tags: gcc

What is the `-lpwl` option? I am trying to run below command for gcc configure:

```
${TOP}/src/gcc/configure --target=${TARGET} --prefix=${CT_BT_PREFIX} --without-headers --with-gmp=${LIBS_BUILD} --with-mpfr=${LIBS_BUILD} --with-mpc=${LIBS_BUILD} --with-ppl=${LIBS_BUILD} --with--cloog=${LIBS_BUILD} --with-host-libstdcxx="-Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm -L${LIBS_BUILD}/lib -lpwl"
```

I get the following error:

```
cc1-checksum.o libbackend.a main.o  libcommon-target.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a   ../libbacktrace/.libs/libbacktrace.a ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm -L/home/swaroop/Final_project/build/libs-for-build/lib -lpwl  -L/home/swaroop/Final_project/build/libs-for-build/lib -L/home/swaroop/Final_project/build/libs-for-build/lib -L/home/swaroop/Final_project/build/libs-for-build/lib -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp -rdynamic -ldl -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm -L/home/swaroop/Final_project/build/libs-for-build/lib -lpwl -L../zlib -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpwl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpwl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cc1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/swaroop/Final_project/build/build-core-pass-1-build/gcc'
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

Comment: `-l<x>` means "link against library <x>", and "pwl" is most likely the parma watchdog library. Are you on Ubuntu?

Comment: yes i am using ubuntu.. !! i get the error when i do "make gcc-all" .. basically i am not able to locate that library

Comment: Try `apt-get instal libpwl-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm converting my comments to an answer then.

> What is the `-lpwl` option?

That is the `-l` (lowercase L) flag with `pwl` as parameter.
`-l<x>` means "link against library <x>", and `pwl` appears to be the "Parma watchdog library".
And evidently, that library is missing from your system.

Now, on Ubuntu this can be solved fairly easily with:

```
apt-get install libpwl-dev
```

However, Ubuntu is not the only system out there, and I have no idea for what systems PWL is available or how to install it on any of them.
There appears to be a [`libpwl-dev` package on debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libdevel/libpwl-dev), but apart from that, I was unable to find any source code, (authoritative) distribution website or documentation regarding PWL at all.
I only found [some commit message](http://www.cs.unipr.it/pipermail/ppl-devel/2012-February/017944.html) stating that "The Parma Watchdog Library has been merged into the Parma Polyhedra Library".
According to that, [PPL](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl/download) should be the way to go.

I can imagine the Ubuntu `libpwl-dev` package being only a placeholder for `libppl-dev`, but I'm not sure about that, and I can't seem to find any `pwl` package at all on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) for anything newer than Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm posting this as community wiki, so if you have any information on PWL, please add to this answer.